# Update a variable if hidden input was changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all i have a hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddeninp" value="0">
```

When i click on this div, value of hidden input need to changed. (example to 1)

```
<div id="inputvalue">change input value to 1</div>
```

I have 2 extra div (display none)

```
<div style="display:none" id ="div0">div 1</div>
<div style="display:none" id ="div1">div 2</div>
```

Now, when i click on `<div id="inputvalue"></div>` hidden input value must to change in 1.

```
$("#inputvalue").click(function() {
  $("#hiddeninp").val(1);
});
```

After hidden input value was changed, i what to display `<div id ="div1"></div>` and hide `<div id ="div0"></div>` (and vice versa when hidden input value is 0)

```
var myvar = $("#hiddeninp").val();

if (myvar == 0) {
  $("#div1").hide();
  $("#div0").show();
} else {
  $("#div0").hide();
  $("#div1").show();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e8a3ewj0/5/

Comment: You have to place the if statements with the hide and show in the click event function. Because right now it only executes the if statements when the page is rendered. When you place it in the click event function, the code  gets executed each time you click the div. This is necessary because you have to check the value after it is changed.

Comment: I can make `on change` event only for  `myvar` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the action of checking the input value, in a separate function and call itr onload and on every click.

Here try this:

```js
$("#inputvalue").click(function() {
  if  ($("#hiddeninp").val() == 1) {
    $("#hiddeninp").val(0);
    $("#inputvalue").text("change input value to 1");
  } else {
    $("#hiddeninp").val(1);
    $("#inputvalue").text("change input value to 0");
  }
  checkStatus();
 
});


var checkStatus = function() {
  var myvar = $("#hiddeninp").val();
  if (myvar == 0) {
    $("#div1").hide();
    $("#div0").show();
  } else {
    $("#div0").hide();
    $("#div1").show();
  }
}

checkStatus();
```

```css
div#inputvalue {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" id="hiddeninp" value="0">


<div id="inputvalue">change input value to 1</div>


<div style="display:none" id ="div0">div 1</div>
<div style="display:none" id ="div1">div 2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

However, you have to do the toggle just after when you change the value. Like if you make a function then you can call it just after changing the value.

You can use:

```
function doToggle(){
    var i = $("#hiddeninp").val();
    $('div[id^="div"]').hide(); // or add a common class="foo" = $('.foo').hide()
    $('#div'+i).show();
}

$("#inputvalue").click(function() {
    $("#hiddeninp").val(1);
    doToggle();
});
```

---

Or this one but not recomended:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e){
   var i       = $("#hiddeninp").val(),
       isinput = $(e.target).is('#inputvalue') || $(e.target).parent().is('#inputvalue');
   $('#div0').toggle(isinput && i == 0);
   $('#div1').toggle(isinput && i == 1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've put my answer here as an answer instead of a comment so I can show you how the code will look like.

You have to place the if statements with the hide and show in the click event function. Because right now it only executes the if statements when the page is rendered. When you place it in the click event function, the code gets executed each time you click the div. This is necessary because you have to check the value after it is changed.

Your code will become this

```
    $("#inputvalue").click(function() {
        $("#hiddeninp").val(1);

        var myvar = $("#hiddeninp").val();

        if (myvar == 0) {
          $("#div1").hide();
          $("#div0").show();
        } else {

          $("#div0").hide();
          $("#div1").show();
        }
    });
```